# asp.net button click event firing twice in Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net button inside UpdatePanel. Sometimes it's click event fire twice and generate duplicate records. My button declaration is..

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" onclick="btnSave_Click" Text="Save"/>
```

and code behind is...

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SaveData();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sometimes or always? Is it because you are clicking multiple times or its happening with only one click'

Comment: sometimes it happen and with only one click

Comment: are there any anchor tags like this in your aspx page <a ref="#"></a> ? where ref="#"

Comment: No, there is no anchor tags in my aspx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `UseSubmitBehavior` attribute to  `asp:Button`

```
UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
OnClientClick="this.disabled='true' ; this.value= 'Please Wait..';"
```

Comment: Thank You! My problem was solved by your instruction.